# alloc, init, and new in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

One book for about iPhone programming instantiates classes like this:

```
[[Class alloc] init]
```

Another book about Objective-C does it like this:

```
[Class new]
```

What's the difference?

Comment: What about `[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];`

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Originally in Objective-C, objects were created with new. As the OpenStep/Cocoa framework evolved, the designers developed the opinion that allocating the memory for an object and initializing its attributes were separate concerns and thus should be separate methods (for example, an object might be allocated in a specific memory zone). So the alloc-init style of object creation came into favor.

Basically, new is old and almost-but-not-quite deprecated — thus you'll see that Cocoa classes have a lot of init methods but almost never any custom new methods.

Comment: Could you show or cite where +new is "almost-but-not-quite deprecated".  I'd like to have the info before I discuss with colleagues.

Comment: I use it as a shortcut when all I wan't to do is call `alloc`/`init`.

Comment: What about [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

Comment: What is a memory zone and why would it be needed to be allocated in a specific one?

Answer (score 78):

`+new` is implemented quite literally as:

```
+ (id) new
{
    return [[self alloc] init];
}
```

Nothing more, nothing less.   Classes might override it, but that is highly atypical in favor of doing something like `+fooWithBar:`.

Answer (score 15):

As already mentioned, by defaut there is no difference. But you can overwrite the `new` class method. [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/new) has some thoughts on this.

> Unlike *alloc*, *new* is sometimes
>   re-implemented in subclasses to invoke
>   a class-specific initialization
>   method[...] Often *new...* methods will
>   do more than just allocation and
>   initialization.

Comment: I don't see the excerpt in your link.  Could you site your source, please?

Comment: Obviously, Apple has updated the docs and removed that paragraph. You can find copies of older versions on the web (not sure about copyright...)

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the Class, but `[Class new]` is most likely a convenience method that calls `[[Class alloc] init]` internally. Thus, you can not call other init methods such as "initWithString".

Comment: “alloc” creates a new memory location but doesn’t initializes it as compared to “new”.