# Allocating/Initialising objects

Tags: objective-c

Was just wondering, which way is better to fully initialise an object:

```
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

OR

```
NSString *myString = [NSString new];
```

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [alloc, init, and new in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330963/alloc-init-and-new-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

This is the preferred way. The majority of code I have seen for iPhone does not use `new`. Don't for get to `release` it if you use `alloc` then `init`.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no difference at all between `new` and `alloc`+`init`; `new` is just a "convenience allocator." That said, one typically sees `alloc`+`init` used more than `new`, simply for the sake of consistency.