# Use-case of +new in Cocoa? And why it exist?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [alloc, init, and new in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330963/alloc-init-and-new-in-objective-c)

There is `+alloc/-init...` and `+new`. Their role are almost same in documentation except `+new` is designed for instance pooling. (according to my understanding :)

However the pooling is possible with `+alloc/-init`. Why the separated method is required? Or is there any reason for the method?

And I couldn't find any example utilizes the method. When should I use this method? Can I get some use-case of the method `+new`?

Comment: I agree with duplication. Sorry:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original Objective-C implementation from Stepstone, `+new` was what  we used to create instances. It was a holdover from Smalltalk.  NeXT separated `+new` into `+alloc`/`-init` since most classes don't have to do anything different to allocate the memory their instances use, and it didn't make sense to duplicate that code all over the place.

Comment: `+[NSOject new]` is implemented as `return [[self alloc] init]`. Bear that in mind if using `new`, since this means that the designated initializer is not guaranteed to be called. In short; avoid `new`.