# Calling new for allocation objects in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of alloc init instead of new (Objective-C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719877/use-of-alloc-init-instead-of-new-objective-c)

Does any of you use `+new` of the `NSObject` to alloc & init the object?

Lets say i got an object C derived from Object B which all are from `NSObject`. To create an instance of Object C

```
C newInstanceOfC = [C new]; // This will call the alloc & init of class C.
```

is this any better than

```
C newInstanceOfC = [C alloc] init];
```

other than less things to type. What is good practice?

cheers
Arun

Comment: You can even do "instance = C.new" though personally I don't care for that form.

Comment: new is the old way check the link @darvidsOn. It gave me the rite answer.

Answer (score 1):

`alloc] init]` is best practice. In particular, objects have different ways to `init`, including zero, one or more than one parameter. Using `new` makes an automatic selection of `init`, but having `init` visible can help you troubleshoot some nasty bugs that can happen if you initialise a UI element but forget to set the `frame`, etc.. You'll get compiler warnings about the use of the `init` method in some circumstances too.

Answer (score 0):

They are both exactly the same, new is the new way, as that wasn't possible before, but use the one that you like the most.

I usually use new since it is shorter, although in several cases you can't since you usually want to do something like:

```
[[myObject] alloc] initWith...];
```

Comment: `new` is the _old_ way. That was the preferred NeXTSTEP procedure. At some point, it was realized that separating the allocation and initialization made certain things easier (`[[NSArray alloc] initWithCapacity:]`), and now `alloc`/`init` is the preferred way in Cocoa. See Chuck's and especially bbum's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330963/alloc-init-and-new-in-objective-c

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Separating alloc and init doesn't make `initWithCapacity:` any easier as far as I can tell — it would just be `newWithCapacity:` instead. To the best of my knowledge, what it made easier was primarily memory zones.

Comment: @Chuck: Thanks for that note. I admit I've never been quite clear on the reasoning; `initWithCapacity:` seemed sensible, but apparently was a bad guess.