# What is the difference between [Class new] and [[Class alloc] init] in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, new-operator, allocation, init

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [alloc, init, and new in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330963/alloc-init-and-new-in-objective-c)

I am a little confused about `[Class new]` and  `[[Class alloc] init]`. I have defined an object `content` using `[Class new]` and  `[[Class alloc] init]`.

```
(1). NSMutableArray *content = [NSMutableArray new];
(2). NSMutableArray *content = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

My question is about the differences between `[Class new]` and `[[Class alloc] init]`. For me, (1) and (2) are similar. If (1) and (2) are similar, then why do we use `[[Class alloc] init]` most of the time, compared to `[Class new]`? I think that there must be some difference.

Kindly explain the differences, pros & cons of both?

Comment: you can refer to this link http://macresearch.org/difference-between-alloc-init-and-new

Answer (score 134, accepted):

**Alloc:** Class method of NSObject. Returns a new instance of the receiving class.

**Init**: Instance method of NSObject. Implemented by subclasses to initialize a new object (the receiver) immediately after memory for it has been allocated.

**New**: Class method of NSObject. Allocates a new instance of the receiving class, sends it an init message, and returns the initialized object.

**Release**: Instance method of NSObject delegate. Decrements the receiver’s reference count.

**Autorelease**: Instance method of NSObject delegate. Adds the receiver to the current autorelease pool.

**Retain:** Instance method of NSObject delegate. Increments the receiver’s reference count.

**Copy:** Instance method of NSObject delegate. Returns a new instance that’s a copy of the receiver.

So to conclude we can say that

**alloc goes with init**

**new = alloc + init**

Comment: Delegates don't really have anything to do with this. Do you mean `NSObject` **protocol**?

Answer (score 29):

The `+new` method is simply shorthand for `+alloc` and `-init`. The ownership semantics are identical. The only benefit to using `+new` is that it is more concise. If you need to provide arguments to the class's initialiser, you will have to use the `+alloc` and `-initWith...` methods instead.

Answer (score 9):

Here: [alloc, init, and new in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330963/alloc-init-and-new-in-objective-c)

Basically it's a question of modern versus traditional. The most direct advantage of init over new is that there are many custom init methods.