# Which one is better alloc init or new

Tags: ios

I am confused in this can you tell me which one is better and why?

I read somewhere that this both are used for allocing and initializing. somebody was telling me that you cant do like newWithString and all other things like that but when I tried in Xcode then Its not giving me error

```
      NSString *AddEmail  =[[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"Add Email"];

      NSString *AddEmail  =[NSString new];
```

do both will work In same way?

thank you in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330963/alloc-init-and-new-in-objective-c

Comment: Where did you find this method newWithString:?

Comment: i dont know i just tired in my Xcode and no error

Comment: Is this on a new project you created? There is no method newWithString in the iOS SDK...

Comment: then why not showing red error? you try in your Xcode wont show error

Comment: Maybe you meant `stringWithString:`?

Comment: @PrakashDesai Obviously __newWithString__ shows error. There is no such method

Comment: Ok i got the answer my xcode is not working properly need to update it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[[SomeClass alloc] init]` will give the same result as `[SomeClass new]`. new is implemented as

```
+ (id) new
{
    return [[self alloc] init];
}
```

The `newWithString` method you use gives a quite explicit warning : "Class method `+newWithString` not found", so even if you code compile, it will fail on this line. (Unless you declared a category on `NSString`).

I tend to prefer `[[alloc] init]`, because you can allocate an object then choose how you will initialize its variables, according to the init method you chose..

Comment: Yes i got it my xcode has some problem not showing me error but compile time error

Answer (score 1):

`+[NSString new]` simply returns an empty, immutable string.

It is equivalent to `[[NSString alloc] init]`.

Your examples are not the same. If I were to correctly guess your intention, `NSString * AddEmail = @"Add Email";` would be all you would need to write. You do not need to use `+alloc`, `-initWithString:`, `+stringWithString:`, etc. in this example because `@"Add Email"` is already an `NSString`.

`[[TYPE alloc] init]` and `[TYPE new]` are equivalent (unless overridden). Which you choose is your preference. I prefer `[TYPE new]` because it is shorter and there is no need to separate (or pronounce) the alloc/init message chain whenever you create a 'new' object.