# Difference between new and array initializations

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays

Is there a difference between the initializations `[NSArray new]` and `[NSArray array]`?

[`array`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSArray/array) seems to be part of the implementation of `NSArray` while [`new`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/new) belongs to `NSObject`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**new  = alloc + init**

> This method is a combination of alloc and init. Like alloc, it
>   initializes the isa instance variable of the new object so it points
>   to the class data structure. It then invokes the init method to
>   complete the initialization process.

[NSObject Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/new)

`+new` is implemented quite literally as:

```
+ (id) new
{
    return [[self alloc] init];
}
```

and `new` doesn't support custom initializers (like `initWithObjects`), so `alloc + init` is more explicit than `new`

So the question now is about:

**[NSArray array] vs [[NSArray alloc] init]**

> The main difference between these is if you're not using ARC
>   (Automatic Reference Counting). The first one returns a retained and
>   autoreleased object. The second one returns an object that is only
>   retained. So in the first case, you would want to retain it if you
>   wanted to keep it around for longer than the current run loop. In the
>   second case, you would want to release or autorelease it if you didn't
>   want to keep it around.
>
> Now that we have ARC, this changes things. Basically, in ARC code, it
>   doesn't matter which of these you use.

But keep in mind that `[NSArray array]` returns an empty immutable array, so using `array` with `NSMutableArray` makes more sense

***For more information:***

[alloc, init, and new in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3331066/1836115)

[Use of alloc init instead of new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719877/use-of-alloc-init-instead-of-new)

[Difference between [NSMutableArray array] vs [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719877/use-of-alloc-init-instead-of-new)

Comment: Adding up to this answer, regarding [NSArray array], it generates an empty immutable array. It's quite useless to do this obviously (like using new), but it changes when using a NSMutableArray. The thing is, as @Aladin mentioned, now that we have ARC, It does not make any difference.

Comment: Comes down to syntax usage I think and preference.

Comment: It is not completely useless, you can do something like `NSArray *arr = [NSArray array]; NSArray *arr2 = [arr arrayByAddingObject:@"ha!"];`. It may be useful.. at some point.. i guess